# How to draw line starts from one point and pass through another point and extends upto axis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to draw a line starts from a certain point,, and it should pass through another point and extend upto plot axis as shown below[image]. How can i do that? I know how to generate line between two points, but is there any instruction to extend the line as in figure?

I tried below code;

```
A = [2 6]; 
B = [3 6]; 
axis([0 10 0 10])
plot(A,B)

xlim([2,10])
ylim([3,10])
```

But I am not getting plot as I required. Can anyone reply? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `interp1` function for linear extrapolation, if you want to draw straight line.

```
Xq=[A 10];

Yq=interp1(A,B,Xq,'linear','extrap')

plot(Xq,Yq,'*-')
```